# How does SelectedListViewItemCollection implement IList but not have Add()?

Tags: c#, winforms, interface, .net-2.0

I am trying to mimic the way a ListView and other controls handle SelectedItems collections.  I have a class with a collection of items and each Item has a Selected property.

I want to mimic the smart behavior where an Item can change its own Selected property and upon doing so would raise a SelectedItemsChanged event in the parent class, and the SelectedItems collection should now reflect the change.

I am trying to implement a SelectedItemsCollection class which does not contain an inner list but instead checks the Selected state of each item in the main Items list.  This way it doesn't need to be constantly updated and synchronized with the main list.

I was looking at the metadata for ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection and it has the following declaration:

```
public class SelectedListViewItemCollection : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

It does not implement Add, Remove, RemoveAt, etc.  Isn't this against the rules of using the IList interface?  I cannot compile without implementing them.  Is this just a glitch in the way the metadata is created?

How should I go about emulating this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those methods are implemented [**explicitly**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
For example disassembling the class with ILspy you can see that the `Add()` method is implemented as follows:

```
int IList.Add(object value)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

So, for instance if you have an instance of `SelectedItemsCollection` and you want to invoke the `Add()` method, you must cast the object to `IList` e.g. :

```
((IList)mySelectedItemsCollection).Add(...)
```

And yes, if you look at the metadata of the class through Visual Studio, the explicitly implemented methods are hidden.

About the `Selected` property... well the *"trick"* is that each item has a reference to the `ListView` it belongs to. When `Selected` property changes, the item calls  `SetSelectedState()` method of the listView that raises a `SelectedChanged` event.

Also `SelectedItemsCollection` is created passing the `ListView` reference in the constructor, in this way the enumerations of the elements is actually performed on an inner member of ListView that is accessible from `SelectedItemsCollection` because it's a nested class.

Comment: Added a little explanation of how `Selected` and `SelectedItemsCollection` work.